# Chai Http Post : save entity to mongodb Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing a test for a route which save an entity to mongodb.
The route works fine when using postman, but fail when runing chai http test.

The error thrown is either:

> Error: read ECONNRESET

Or sometimes:

> Error: socket hang up.

I don't get what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate if someone could help me or point me on a direction.
Cheers

Server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const database = require('./controller/databaseController');
const router = require('./routes/router');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app =  express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/", router);

database.connect();

app.listen(port, () => {

    console.log( "serveur launched, listening on port " + port );
    console.log("environment : " + app.settings.env);

});

//export app for testing purpose
module.exports = app;
```

Route code:

```
router.post('/savePharmacie', (req, res) => {

    var pharmacie = new PharmacieModel(req.body);

    pharmacie.save((err, doc) => {

        if(err){

            res.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
            res.json(err);
            res.end();

        }else{

            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
            res.json(doc);
            res.end();

        }

    });

});
```

Test code:

```
describe('save to database', () => {

    it('save one to database', (done) => {

        chai.request(app)
        .post('saveData/savePharmacie')
        .send(pharmacieMockup)
        .end((err, resp,  body) => {

            if(err){

                console.log("error : " + err);

                done(err);

            }else{

                var response = res.body;     
                console.log("response : " + response);               
                var expected = [pharmacieMockup];                    

                response.should.be.a('array');
                expect(response[0]).to.deep.include(expected[0]);

                done();


            }

        });


    });

    after((done) => {

        PharmacieModel.deleteMany({});
        done();

    });


});
```

The `pharmacieMockup` object is a dummy json object which follow the mongoose schema.

The `app` object reference a express server instance.

The route tested ('saveData/savePharmacie') is the one describe in the upper (router.post).

Comment: Please provide more information about your test setup. Where the app object came from? Is your test passing through a fake app object or real http requests?

Comment: @lifeisfoo : thanks for your remark, I added some more information. The app object is an express server instance and the test pass through a reall http requests, the code handling this http request is the one below Routes

Comment: how are you exporting your app from your main js file? How are you starting/binding your server (code like `.listen()`)?

Comment: @lifeisfoo I added the whole server.js file, and yes I use app.listen(portNbr), and module.exports = app to get access to app from my test.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is caused by the `app.listen` function: this is an async function so when you import your main server file you can't be sure it's running.

Then, the [chai http lib](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http#application--server) documantation say:

> You may use a function (such as an express or connect app) or a node.js http(s) server as the foundation for your request. If the server is not running, chai-http will find a suitable port to listen on for a given test.

So, I suggest you to [separate your express app and server](https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/projectstructre/separateexpress.md) using two files: in this way you can import your express app in your tests without external async functions to be handled.

This is a minimal example of the suggested structure:

File `app.js`:

```
const app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200);
});
module.exports = app
```

File `bin/app` (file with no extension):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// the above line is required if you want to make it directly executable
// to achieve this you need to make it executable using "chmod +x bin/app"  from you shell, but it's an optional only required if you want to run it using "./bin/app" without an npm script.

var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || '3000');

var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Then update your package.json file with a new run script:

```
"scripts": {
  //...
  "start-app": "node ./bin/app",
}
```

Now you can run you app using `npm run start-app`. Your test code should remain the same, imporing only the `app.js` file with a `require` command.

Comment: thanks for your help, I never seen a file such as bin/app , especially the "#!/usr/bin/env node". what should be the extension of the file ?

Comment: i just tried it and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help and for this best practice